unable to find demo_nodes_cpp code
I would like to inspect the code for the talker in the package of demo_nodes_cpp but I can't find it.
I found /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/demo_nodes_cpp/talker but it has no extension and it's codificated.
Any idea where to find it? I found it on https://github.com/ros2/demos but not in the framework.

You can find the cpp file in this link: the link
talker is the executable name, talker.cpp is the file name.

but is it possible to find them inside the prebuilt package without hitting to GitHub?

You need to look at to CMakeLists.txt for to find out which file turns out which executable. When you look at it, you'll see talker.cpp file's executable name is talker. Then you should look the talker.cpp in the package/repository
